# redirects in php exec are broken in apache + windows7, were working on windowsXP

Tags: php, windows, apache, io-redirection

i have been using PHP to execute a legacy script in an Apache server. the legacy script writes debug data to STDERR and i have been redirecting that to a black-hole or STDOUT depending on the debug-settings.

the PHP looks a bit like this:

```
exec('perl -e "print 10; print STDERR 20" 2>&1', $output);
```

that was reliably working in XP. i got new hardware which now runs windows7 and coming back to this code it is broken. zero output. return-code 255. no idea why.

the only way i was able to get it going again was to remove the redirection. oh, redirection still works perfectly in a terminal-box.

now i have to retrieve my debug-data from the apache-error-log (where every STDERR output goes by default) which is inconvenient but not a problem.

i just want to understand why the redirect stopped working all of a sudden (and maybe help others running into the same problem). the apache is the same, in fact i just copied the XAMPP dir over from the old box. a bug? system-limitation? forbidden by OS-policy?

Comment: You were probably using Win XP 32 bit against now using Win 7 64 bit, which causes conflicts in some dll's of your PHP which are compiled to be 32 bit. Reinstall the whole xampp package, or built your own downloading separately php and apache, but this time fittable for your OS (if it's 64 bit, install 64 bit PHP)

Comment: I'm not a Windows users, but after a search I see the stderr redirection exists in XP documentation but is missing for Win7. Maybe it's been removed?

Comment: your theory sounds valid. indeed i was using xp-32 before and win7-54 now. i will have to see if i can upgrade xampp to test your theory. - i have not been looking at the docs for win7 but i tested the whole command as it should have been EXEC'd in a "dos-box" which worked fine

Comment: it seems like only PHP 5.5 is available in 64-bit and those seem to be experimental for windows -> http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.5 I need to use an older version of PHP to be compatible with the production servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `exec` and using filehandle redirection, use [`proc_open`](http://php.net/proc_open) and actually capture the output of stdout and stderr.  Unlike some of the process-related functions, the `proc_` family is built in to all versions of PHP and work fine on Windows.

A c&p of their example for completeness:

```
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("file", "/tmp/error-output.txt", "a") // stderr is a file to write to
);

$cwd = '/tmp';
$env = array('some_option' => 'aeiou');

$process = proc_open('php', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env);

if (is_resource($process)) {
    // $pipes now looks like this:
    // 0 => writeable handle connected to child stdin
    // 1 => readable handle connected to child stdout
    // Any error output will be appended to /tmp/error-output.txt

    fwrite($pipes[0], '<?php print_r($_ENV); ?>');
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);

    // It is important that you close any pipes before calling
    // proc_close in order to avoid a deadlock
    $return_value = proc_close($process);

    echo "command returned $return_value\n";
}
```

Be sure to browse the *upvoted* user-contributed notes on the documentation page for possible caveats.

Comment: I just tried process_open and handed it the three pipes as r,w,w like in the example. the simple "perl print.." works and i get my 10 into STDOUT and 20 into STDERR. nice! running the same thing with my big legacy code just freezes. i can see PERL running in the task-manager but it does not come back. putting prints into the script i see it hangs on reading STDOUT with "stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);". following your advise about the comments i turned my STDERR pipe into 'a' (or even 'a+') and i get my STDOUT back as expected but zero STDERR anymore. *stumped-again*

Comment: fun fact: it seems like i remember that the php-timeout _does run_ when the process control is with another binary, but cannot be enforced. so now i have this php-script executing a wedged PERL process and that's it. it is stuck somewhere and will now run for eternity. not such a problem for my desktop. horrific outlook for a server. as soon as i kill PERL with the task-manager, i get the "whoa, your php ran too long" message printed and the script gets killed without getting the chance to clean up.

Comment: if i use the taskmanager to kill the PERL process i get STDERR, but no STDOUT. if i tell PERL not to do debug-printing (which causes nothing to be written to STDERR) everything works flawless. reading and closing streams right away does not change the problem regardless of order (STDERR or STDIN first or the other way round).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i got the (well maybe at least my) solution:

1. use proc_open as Charles suggested
2. go back to the original principle of io_redirection

dumping stuff directly to STDERR and retrieving it from there via pipes does apparently not work under (my) windows7+PHP with my code. simple examples work, but that was it for me.

so while using `2>&1` broke my exec() - the initial problem -  it works wonderfully with proc_open(). problem solved.

i wonder if i will now find something broken on our linux servers running the new code.

small caveat: if you don't want your code to print to STDERR and you use redirect-to-null e.g. for production, in windows it's `2>nul`